# I build this linear regression function from scratch and checked the formulas but the values are exceeding the limit of numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

Here is the function I build for Linear Regression

```
def grad(X,Y,ite=1000,alp=0.1):
    
    l = X.shape[0] #to store total number of sample data
    n = 0 #to store the dimnsion of the array to be made for the weight vector
    bias = 0
    try: #to catch if the sample contains only one function
        n = X.shape[1]
    except:
        n = 1

    weight = np.zeros(n) #initializing the weight vector
    

    def h(weight,x): #the linear regression line function
        if weight.shape == (1,n):
            return np.matmul(weight.T,x)
        else: return np.matmul(weight,x)

    for i in range(ite):#looping through 
        s = 0 #to store the sum of (y-h(x))x
        b = 0 #to store the sum of bias
        for x,y in zip(X,Y):
            s += 1/l * (y - h(weight,x) + bias) * x
            b += 1/l * (y - h(weight,x) + bias)
        
        #updating the weights and bias
        weight -= alp * s
        bias -= alp * b
    
    return weight,bias
```

for the input I took as

```
X = np.array([
    [1],
    [2],
    [3]
])
y = np.array([[1],
             [2],
             [3]])
w,b = grad(X,y)
print(w,b)
```

the output to this is:
`[-1.68165173e+141] [-6.94859255e+140]`

I tried looking up the formula and the code but could'nt make any improvements.

Okay,
I made the update to the formula where

```
s += 2/l * (h(weight,x) + bias - y) * x
b += 2/l * (h(weight,x) + bias - y)
```

and

```
weight -= alp * s
bias -= alp * b
```

the function is working correctly for the above input data but when the data is large something like

```
X = np.array([
    [11.45],
    [22.45],
    [33.45]
])

y = np.array([
    [22.9],
    [44.9],
    [66.9]
])
```

then the weight and bias becomes [nan] [nan]

```
[nan] [nan]
/var/folders/cz/lky96vlx5b3gt97txms5jymm0000gn/T/ipykernel_86176/3700417253.py:24: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  s += 2/l * (h(weight,x) + bias - y) * x
/var/folders/cz/lky96vlx5b3gt97txms5jymm0000gn/T/ipykernel_86176/3700417253.py:28: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  weight -= alp * s
```

Comment: What is your expected output? (`(1, 0)`?) How does changing `ite` and `alp` affect your output - and is that doing what you expect? Can you post the formula/algorithm you're using for reference?

Comment: http://cs229.stanford.edu/summer2019/cs229-notes1.pdf ,this is the reference to the formula that I used. And also looked up on the internet further.
The expected answer is (1,0)

Comment: @R.A.Y.27 check the formula at the bottom of page 4. The gradient looks like `(h(x) - y) * x` but you have the opposite sign, like `(y - h(x)) * x`.

Comment: There are several methods described in the notes that you linked but nothing that looks quite like your program. You'll need to clarify and provide more details of why you're doing what you're doing.

Comment: @slothrop thank :), made the update but now there is another problem, which eventually was the original problem

Comment: I'm guessing you might get some overshoot because the initial gradient will be very large. Does it converge if you use a smaller value of alpha?